# Block selection or multiple cursors in Texstudio?

Tags: editor, textselection, multiple-cursor, texstudio

The [website of Texstudio](https://texstudio.org) advertises block selection or multiple cursor functionality, but I could not figure out which key combination to use for this feature reading their horribly cryptic [user-manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html).

I am familiar with how text selection with multiple cursors works in Sublime Text, for instance. Those key combinations don't work here.

Would someone be kind enough to please tell me how to do this in Texstudio? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key combination for block selection is `Shift`+`Ctrl`+`Alt` (See [Sect. 2.8.1 in Manual](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/master/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION18a))

Press them all together and simultaneously move the **mouse** or cursors to select the text.

Alternatively, `Ctrl`+`Alt` can be used to place multiple cursors without selecting, even in the same line or in non adjacent lines.

Without the mouse, you can use `Ctrl`+`Alt` and `Up`/`Down` arrows keys to place multicursors.

And for special use cases, there is Edit/Searching/Select All Matches, to create multi cursors after searching text with the search bar.

Edit/Selection/Select All Occurernces is like Edit/Searching/Select All Matches, but for the current word (the one where the cursor is currently placed) rather than the search.

In TeXstudio 3.0.0, there are  new commands  Edit/Selection/Also Select Next|Prev Occurrence to create multiple cursors to the next|prev occurrence of the current word.

Comment: On macs, it is `Cmd+Opt` (`⌘⌥`). Got it. Thanks.

Comment: how's it on Linux?

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.Gutiérrez-Vargas on Linux it should be like in the post